# WKWebView loadHTMLString

Tags: ios, objective-c, wkwebview

I use WKWebView to load the html string returned from the server, and set the CSS, but the page does not show the phone screen, how can I do?

```
 NSString *requestUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://news-at.zhihu.com/api/4/news/%ld",self.story.ID];
requestSuccessBlock sblock = ^(id responseObject){

    YAContentItem *content = [YAContentItem contentItemWithKeyValues:responseObject];


    NSString *htmlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html><head><link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href=%@ /></head><body>%@</body></html>", content.css.firstObject, content.body];


    [self.webView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:nil];
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
- (WKWebView *)webView {
if (_webView == nil) {

    WKWebView *webView = [[WKWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, kScreenWidth, kScreenHeight - 44)];

    // 自适应屏幕宽度js
    NSString *jSString = @"var meta = document.createElement('meta'); meta.setAttribute('name', 'viewport'); meta.setAttribute('content', 'width=device-width'); document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(meta);";
    WKUserScript *wkUserScript = [[WKUserScript alloc] initWithSource:jSString injectionTime:WKUserScriptInjectionTimeAtDocumentEnd forMainFrameOnly:YES];
    WKUserContentController *contentController = webView.configuration.userContentController;

    // 添加自适应屏幕宽度js调用的方法
    [contentController addUserScript:wkUserScript];

    webView.navigationDelegate = self;

    [self.view addSubview:webView];

    _webView = webView;
    [self.view addSubview:webView];
}
return _webView;
```

}